# How to use missForest in R for test data imputation?

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data, data-imputation, example

I want to use the R `missForest()` function at work to perform missing value imputation. However, after reading up on the algorithm more, I can't decide how to impute future/test data - running the algorithm on *just* the `test` data, or run it on `train` + `test` combined.

I have heard many times that you training & test datasets should not inform one another at all, but this algorithm is an example of where I think that doing so would increase predictive performance a lot, and *crucially* I see no reason why I wouldn't be able to apply this same approach in production for future unseen data.

Here's an example of what i'm proposing. First I do a train/test split and introduce missing values:

```
library(datasets)
library(missForest)
library(randomForest)
data("iris")

# train/test:
set.seed(2)
train_index <- sample(nrow(iris), 120)
feature_train <- as.matrix(iris[train_index, 1:4])
feature_test <- as.matrix(iris[-train_index, 1:4])

# introduce NA's to both:
feature_train[sample(length(feature_train), 40)] <- NA
feature_test[sample(length(feature_test), 10)] <- NA
```

I impute the training data and build a model on the imputed data:

```
imp_feature_train <- missForest(feature_train)$ximp

rf <- randomForest(x = imp_feature_train, y = iris$Species[train_index])
```

**Method 1:**

For the test data, this is the method that I prefer. It uses the imputed training data to inform `missForest()` in imputing the test data. Is there any issue with this, as long as (if the model was put into production) I also used this training data to inform any future data?

```
feature_train_test <- rbind(feature_test, imp_feature_train)

imp_feature_test_v1 <- missForest(feature_train_test)$ximp[1:nrow(feature_test), ]

pred_test_v1 <- predict(rf, imp_feature_test_v1)
sum(pred_test_v1 == iris$Species[-train_index]) # 27
```

The reason I want to use this approach: imagine your training dataset is 1M observations, and you are building a model that must be ran hourly on 1k observations. The 'quality' of the missing value imputations will surely be higher if you use those 1M observations to 'inform' the `missForest()` algorithm, as apposed to simply running the algorithm on the 1k observations alone.

**Method 2:**

This imputes the train and test datasets completely separately. I imagine that performance would degrade considerably as the test dataset gets smaller:

```
imp_feature_test_v2 <- missForest(feature_test)$ximp

pred_test_v2 <- predict(rf, imp_feature_test_v2)
sum(pred_test_v2 == iris$Species[-train_index]) # 26
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Method 1, I think it is a kind of target leakage because you use test data for predicting each NA value.

How about using this modified dataset `rbind(feature_test[each_row], imp_feature_train)`? just predict each 1 data sample.
I am searching for about good imputation example by using missforest.

Comment: Hey, I actually ended up doing a fair bit of work on missforest after asking this question. You might find this useful: https://www.kaggle.com/lmorgan95/missforest-the-best-imputation-algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the article, @LiamMorgan! Probably naive question, but is it safe to say that your missforest implementation can efficiently impute/recover missing data?

Comment: Random forests are notorious for overfitting so I would recommend caution in using it for imputation.  Be sure to verify using simulation the accuracy of confidence interval coverage when using this approach.